# Conditional testing in cypress between 2 selector

Tags: javascript, automated-tests, cypress

```
//1st Selector
cy.get('div.d-flex.justify-content-between.undefined > button.button.button-filled').contains('Yes, delete user');

//2nd selector
cy.get('div.modal.fade.show > div > div > div > div:nth-child(3) > button.button.button-filled').contains('Delete User');
```

So i got 2 selector, can you help me to make if/else condition, if the 1st condition not working then run the 2nd selector?

thank you!

Answer (score 2):

You can compose selectors with a comma between to perform either/or logic.

For example (just using button caption because it seems unique)

```js
const selector1 = ':contains("Yes, delete user")'

const selector = ':contains("Delete User")'

cy.get(`${selector1}, ${selector2}`)
```

If you want you can add all those other selectors, but it looks a bit over-done to me.

Comment: You missed 2 on the end of `selector2`.

Answer (score 1):

If you page has finished loading, you can use the following code to click one button or the other

```js
cy.get('body').then(body => {
  const button1 = body.find('div.d-flex.justify-content-between.undefined > button.button.button-filled:contains("Yes, delete user")')
  const button2 = body.find('div.modal.fade.show > div > div > div > div:nth-child(3) > button.button.button-filled:contains("Delete User")')
  if (button1.length) {
    button1.click()
  } else if if (button1.length) {
    button2.click()
  } else {
    throw new Error('no button to click')
  }
})
```